# Set volume to max in Android

Tags: android, audio

In my app, I am trying to set the volume when playing an audio clip to the maximum level but it doesn't appear to have any affect. I have to manually adjust the volume to the maximum level. Here's my code:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setVolume(1, 1);
```

Answer (score 10):

[AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html)

```
int origionalVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 0);
```

Comment: wrong. It changes the user setting

Comment: So what's the purpose of setVolume for MediaPlayer?

Comment: Yes this works. Not sure what ling means by changing the user setting. Does this mean that using this code will change the volume globally on the device for all audio or just the current audio being streamed?

Comment: @AndroidDev : I think ling.s new in android. you can use this code for max volume

Comment: @AndroidDev it will change volume for all music volume globally

Comment: oh come on you can obviously use the `orignalVolume` to set it back to the user desired volume

Comment: if this code doesn't work, don't forget the MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS permission : 

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />

Answer (score 4):

Use This

it s for total volume

```
AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager) appContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        int valuess = 9;//range(0-15)
mgr.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, valuess, 0);
```

it is for left right while current song is playing...

```
AudioTrack m = (AudioTrack) appContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
m.setStereoVolume(leftVolume, rightVolume);
```

it works for me.

Comment: i get an java.lang.ClassCastException: android.media.AudioManager cannot be cast to android.media.AudioTrack when i try your solution for the current song. any idea why?

Comment: check imports you imported wrong audio manager....

Comment: You have twice the same getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) first casted as AudioManager (correctly) and second casted as AudioTrack (incorrectly) I assume second service should be something else than AUDIO_SERVICE (or even other method)

Comment: while playing the song we need to use AudioTrack

Answer (score 1):

Using AudioManager you can control the volume of media player.

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 20, 0);
```

also from MediaPlayer

```
public void  setVolume  (float leftVolume, float rightVolume)
```

for example you can use this method as,

```
int maxVolume = 100;
float log1=(float)(Math.log(maxVolume-currVolume)/Math.log(maxVolume));
mp.setVolume(1-log1);
```